# Lua & Lighttpd - $_GET equivalent

Tags: post, web, get, lua, lighttpd

What's Lua's equivalent to php's `$_GET` for a web application?

Also if the url is something like `index.cgi?thisisatest` how can I get everything after the question mark?

Comment: It depends on the webserver. Take a look at the existing lua web frameworks and how they solve this: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of lighttpd and mod_magnet, query strings are not parsed automatically so you need to do it yourself. You can find an example [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/AbsoLUAtion), look for "flv-streaming.lua" in the page.

As for your second question, Lorenzo gave you a generic answer, but in mod_magnet you can also use `lighty.env["uri.query"]` as seen in the same example.

Answer (score 0):

Lua in itself is not a language for web development. There are some libraries for that. You can try [luasocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/).

As for your second question:

```
local url = "index.cgi?thisisatest"
local suffix = string.match( url, "^[^?]+?([^?]-)$" )
print( suffix )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your Lua code in Ophal, then you can use the functions: request_uri() and request_path()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lua as a CGI script, os.getenv("QUERY_STRING") will return everything after the question mark/